# OpenGL Video RAM Limits

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, video-memory

I have been trying to make a Cross-platform 2D Online Game, and my maps are made of tiles.
My tileset, which I render the tiles from, is quite huge.
I wanted to know how can I disable hardware rendering, or at least making it more capable.
Hence, I wanted to know what are the basic limits of the video ram, as far as I know, Direct3D has a texture size limits (by that I don't mean the power-of-two texture sizes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a software renderer, link against [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/).

You can get an estimate of the maximum texture size using [these methods](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm#text0120):

> **21.130 What's the maximum size texture map my device will render hardware accelerated?**
>
> A good OpenGL implementation will render with hardware acceleration whenever possible. However, the implementation is free to not render hardware accelerated. OpenGL doesn't provide a mechanism to ensure that an application is using hardware acceleration, nor to query that it's using hardware acceleration. With this information in mind, the following may still be useful:
>
> You can obtain an estimate of the maximum texture size your implementation supports with the following call:
>
> ```
> GLint texSize;
> glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &texSize);
> ```
>
> If your texture isn't hardware accelerated, but still within the size restrictions returned by `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, it should still render correctly.
>
> This is only an estimate, because the `glGet*()` function doesn't know what format, internalformat, type, and other parameters you'll be using for any given texture. OpenGL 1.1 and greater solves this problem by allowing texture proxy.
>
> Here's an example of using texture proxy:
>
> ```
> glTexImage2D(GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, format, type, NULL);
> ```
>
> Note the pixels parameter is NULL, because OpenGL doesn't load texel data when the target parameter is `GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D`. Instead, OpenGL merely considers whether it can accommodate a texture of the specified size and description. If the specified texture can't be accommodated, the width and height texture values will be set to zero. After making a texture proxy call, you'll want to query these values as follows:
>
> ```
> GLint width;
> glGetTexLevelParameteriv(GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, &width);
>
> if (width==0) {
>    /* Can't use that texture */
> }
> ```